# Battery measurement after charge

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, current-measurement, voltage-measurement

I got a Ni-Cd battery (8 AA) 9.6 V, 700mAh. After a 2 hours charge by an AC/DC adaptor (9.6 V, 250 mA) I take the following measurements by the multimeter:

Voltage: 11.28 V (DC)

Current: almost 10 A (DC)

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

NiCd batteries can be up to around 1.4-1.5 V each after a full charge.  This will drop with time and rapidly with use to level off at around 1.2 V for most of the discharge life.  By 900 mV pretty much all the energy is gone.  Going much below that risks damage.

NiCd are usually capable of high current, so 10 A for short periods right after a full charge is also plausible.  They won't last long like that, and that current may damage them.  700 mAh sounds rather low for a AA size.

Apparently your "9.6 V adapter" isn't regulated.  It must have put out at least the 11.3 V you measure near the end of charge for the battery to get that high.

Comment: I just measured the battery. Voltage has a constant value 9.5 V but current started from around 3 A to fall in a minute into 0.2 A. (it's getting even lower but in a slower tempo). Why is this happens?

Comment: @demp: You are contradicting yourself.  You originally said the battery was a 11.3 V, but now you are saying 9.5 V.  A AA NiCd cell should be able to do 3 A for a while.  Of course that falls off as you drain it.  If you are measuring short circuit current then you have probably damaged the battery.  You haven't said how exactly you are measuring this current.

Comment: Let me summarize. Right after battery charge, I had this measurement: 11.3 V, 10 A. I measured again after 6 hours and I got: 9.5 V and a continuously reduced current (from 3 A to 0.2 A). I measured current with a simple multimeter. Do you think I damaged battery?

Comment: @demp: If you put a multimeter in current mode accross the battery, you were essentially shorting it.  That is not good for the battery, nor is the short-circuit current of the battery all that relevant.  Don't do that.